# How do I calculate the probability of collision for four independent choices from a predetermined pool?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have an immutable pool of **100 options** and pull a random choice from the pool **four times**. What is the probability of any one of the four choices being equal to any other choice, assuming all four choices have an independent, equal probability of being drawn?

I came up with this, but intuitively it feels incorrect... Is it really ~12.284%?

$$\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+2\:\cdot \ln\left(2\right)\cdot 100} \approx 12.284...$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

It might help to consider the complementary event, namely that all four choices are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You have $n={{100}\choose{4}}$ different combinations of the 100 options, and so the probability that you make four *different* choices is
\begin{align*}
p=\frac{n}{n}\cdot \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{n-2}{n}\cdot \frac{n-3}{n}=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{n^3}. 
\end{align*}
So (as Nick suggests) the probability you're looking for is $1-p$.